# QJson::fromVariant() cuts off everything after 8th byte

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have following code chunk as a part of `Qt` application:

```
if(query.exec(UeQueries::UeTablePlaces::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PLACES))
{
    QJsonDocument jsonDocument;
    QJsonArray jsonArray;
    QJsonObject jsonObject;

    while(query.next())
    {
        for(int fieldIndex=0; fieldIndex<query.record().count(); fieldIndex++)
        {
            QString fieldName=query.record().fieldName(fieldIndex);

            if(fieldName.contains("IMAGE"))
            {
                qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                         << query.value(fieldIndex);

                jsonObject.insert(query.record().fieldName(fieldIndex),
                                  QJsonValue::fromVariant(QVariant(query.value(fieldIndex))));
            }
            else
            {
                jsonObject.insert(query.record().fieldName(fieldIndex),
                                  QJsonValue::fromVariant(query.value(fieldIndex)));
            }   // if

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << jsonObject[query.record().fieldName(fieldIndex)];
                     /*<< jsonObject.value(query.record().fieldName(fieldIndex));*/
        }   // for

        jsonArray.push_back(jsonObject);
    }   // while

    jsonDocument.setArray(jsonArray);

    fetchedData=jsonDocument.toJson();
}
else
{
    emit this->ueSignalQueryError(query.lastError());
}   // if
```

The purpose of this code is to convert `MySql` query result(s) to  [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#details) which is then send via `TCP/IP` from **server** to **client** application. The particular `MySql` query is:

```
static const QString SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PLACES="SELECT P.ID AS PLACE_ID, P.NAME AS PLACE_NAME, P.X AS PLACE_X, P.Y AS PLACE_Y, F.NAME AS FLOOR_NAME, F.IMAGE AS FLOOR_IMAGE FROM PLACES AS P JOIN FLOORS AS F ON P.FLOOR=F.ID";
```

Now, the problem is that `FLOOR_IMAGE` field is basically of type [MEDIUMBLOB](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details) and it holds [PNG Image][3] in correct fashion since code's first `qDebug()` statement shows **whole binary representation** of `MEDIUMBLOB` field `FLOOR_IMAGE` (as in database), but statement
 `QJsonValue::fromVariant(QVariant(query.value(fieldIndex)))`
corrupts data in a fashion of cutting everything after `8th byte`:

```
virtual void UeTask::run() QJsonValue(string, "�PNG\r\n\u001A\n")
```

which is output second `qDebug()` statement. Why is this happening?

Comment: That's a lot of conversions, have you verified which step is failing?

Comment: @MrEricSir like I said, `QImage::fromData(fetchedImageArray);` returns invalid (`NULL`) image.

Comment: Right, but at that point you've already gone through half a dozen steps -- any one of them could have failed. Have you actually verified that everything _up to that point_ works as expected?

Comment: @MrEricSir all steps up to this method are ok, as you can see from screenshot, the values are filled and ok!

Comment: Just because a value is "filled" doesn't mean it's correct, which is what I'm asking about here.

Comment: [`QImage::fromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fromData) returns a null image when loading from data fails. That means the data you are loading from is corrupt. In fact, I can see that there are two additional bytes at the beginning of the `fetchedImageArray` in the screen shot you provided. PNG files should always start with `0x89` followed by the letters `PNG`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header). In your screenshot, there are three symbols before the letters `PNG`.

Comment: You need to check the way you are parsing your JSON string, and make sure you are serializing data right from the other end.

Comment: @Mike I've reformated the question, since I've found a bug, I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: @KernelPanic , can you write an MCVE that can reproduce the issue? If the issue resides in `QJson::fromVariant()`, please try to write a minimal test case. And if the issue is not related to MySql, the issue would be much clearer if you wrote an MCVE that does not depend on MySql.